# Error Template isn't shown correctly wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

After i only need to validate one property, i decided to write a Validation rule instead of IDataErrorInfo. I wrote this style:

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource enableStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="validationErrorTemplate">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
             </Style>
```

I just figured out that this trigger is working right. But the default error template (red border) only will be shown if a valid value before the invalid was put in. A custom template changes nothing:

```
<Style.Setters>
  <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
       <ControlTemplate>
          <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red">
             <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
          </Border>
       </ControlTemplate>
     </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style.Setters>
```

Comment: I'm guessing your binding is not set up right.  Are you using `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`?

Comment: _"How can I call the converter before the validator?"_ -- typically, you would put the conversion code somewhere that can be shared by your `ValidationRule` and `IValueConverter` objects. I agree that it sounds like you haven't set `UpdateSourceTrigger` correctly, but since you didn't include a good [mcve] in your question, there's no way to know for sure.